# Origin of transliteration of ~j/sw to ~r in Mandarin

Tags: pronunciation, topolect, transliteration

In Malaysia/Singapore, “Raja” is often transliterated to 拉惹，although Wikipedia uses 拉者as the name for its article on the title.
e.g. Ayer Rajah 亚逸拉惹
Perlis’s Raja 玻璃市拉惹（https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-sg/%E7%8E%BB%E7%92%83%E5%B8%82%E6%8B%89%E6%83%B9）

拉*惹*勒南 Ra*ja*ratnam
惹兰 (Jalan) also frequently appears in street names. Why is 惹 used to transliterate ~ja other languages?

On a perhaps unrelated note, why is 瑞 in 瑞士 and 瑞典used to transliterate the ~sw/su in Swiss or Sweden?

Were 瑞/惹 read something like sw/ja respectively in a more popular dialect of Chinese when such transliterations were standardised? Are there other examples of transliterations into Chinese reflecting dialectal pronunciations (e.g. 麦当劳 McDonald’s?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

瑞 is seoi6 (IPA: /sɵy̯²²/) [in Cantonese](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2582/), and sūi (IPA: /sui²²/) [in Hokkien](https://www.moedict.tw/'%E7%91%9E), so is a fairly close match to the French word *Suisse* and the English name for *Sweden*. The origin of a lot of translations for smaller Western countries came from the Chinese varieties of the southern ports of Guangzhou (Canton) and Xiamen (Amoy) amongst others.

惹 in [some varieties of Hokkien](https://www.moedict.tw/'%E6%83%B9) (specifically Zhangzhou, which gave rise to Penang's variety) is pronounced jiá (IPA: /d͡ʑia⁵³/), which again is a closer match to the voiced affricate of -ja ज in Sanskrit-derived Indo-Aryan languages.

The 者 version is one option that Mandarin has (being an affricate, and in right area of the mouth), and also has the right semantic connotations (representing a person).

Although it is not a general phenomenon, topolectally-divergent transliteration is still a thing. Compare how [Mainland Chinese](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%A4%A7%E5%8D%AB%C2%B7%E8%B4%9D%E5%85%8B%E6%B1%89%E5%A7%86), Malaysians and Singaporeans transliterate David Beckham's surname (貝克漢姆, simpl. 贝克汉姆) with how [Hong Kongers/Macanese](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%A4%A7%E5%8D%AB%C2%B7%E8%B4%9D%E5%85%8B%E6%B1%89%E5%A7%86) do so (碧咸), with how [Taiwanese](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%A4%A7%E5%8D%AB%C2%B7%E8%B4%9D%E5%85%8B%E6%B1%89%E5%A7%86) do so (貝克漢).